# Elasticsearch: Exclude some known fields from full text seach

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to improve full text search functionality of our application which is based on elasticsearch. I have documents with unknown list of additional properties which should be searchable after document is indexed, but also I have list of known properties which are technical metadata, so I want to exclude these properties from full text search.

Currently this functionality is implemented using `fuzzy_like_this` query and this query has `fields` property, but you have to specify full path to all fields you want to search against. In my case it's not an option because I don't know beforehand list of fields, and I would like to specify exclude list.

I have considered to use solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23205583/793874) to set *index* to **no** for these metadata fields, but it's also not an option because I need to filter by some of this fields, thus I do need to index them.

I created [issue on github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6674), which perfectly fits to what I want to have but it's still open.

Could anybody please help with any possible solution or workaround here?

Answer (score 2):

By default, everything will be analyzed for full text search. You will need to specify a [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) in order to prevent the fields from getting analyzed. The way you can do it is by send a PUT request to your index. 
A sample mapping may look like:

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "properties": {
                "country": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "modified_date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "posted_date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

You will need to send it to your index. E.g

`curl -XPUT http://elasticsearch:9200/myindex/ -d '{MAPPING}'`

Please see [this link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings) for more information. Note that, you cannot change a field once. So you will need to delete your document first and then send the mapping.

Comment: If you set mapping to be `non_analyzed` for particular field, it won't be analyzed only, but actual value of this field will be indexed and will be searchable using full text search.

Comment: See the link I gave at the end: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings . You can set index:no to make it non-searchable

Comment: index:no makes it not filterable as well, but I need to filter by this field.